# Decidability problem for one-formula sequent in first order logic

Tags: logic, decidability

I have a question about first order logic : is the problem of provability of one formula in first order logic decidable?

I know that for a sequent $ A \vdash B $ it's undecidable, because $ A $ can be infinite and therefore contain Peano Arithmetic. But I'm talking about a finite number or formula.

I want to be very clear for this decision problem. So let me formalize it. For all $ n \in \mathbb{N} $, we give us a countable number of relation symbols and of function symbols of arity n. We give us a countable number of variables. We use a classic encoding on the integer (I think it's easy to do, but tell me if you think I'm wrong) to encode a first order formula in this language. And I want to know if there exists a Turing machine that is decidable and that accept a number if and only if it's the encoding of a formula for which $ \vdash A $ is provable.

Ask me if anything seems unclear, I'll be happy to give more details.

Wikipedia is not very clear about that question and I don't find any (accessible or satisfying) reference. Do you have any? or do you have an answer with a proof?

Thank you for reading me, I hope my English in understandable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still undecidable: there are **finitely axiomatizable** theories to which Godel's theorem still applies. The most dramatic example is probably [Robinson's Q](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic) on account of its incredible weakness, but there are others including ACA$_0$ *(a theory of natural numbers and sets of natural numbers which plays a central role in [reverse mathematics](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/sosoa/chapter1.pdf))* and NBG *(a "set theory" which also talks about proper classes and often provides a more natural framework for metamathematical statements than ZFC)*.

---

ACA$_0$ and NBG have an interesting feature: each is in a sense a finitely axiomatizable version of a better-known non-finitely-axiomatizable theory, namely PA and ZFC respectively. Roughly speaking, ACA$_0$ is a finitely-axiomatizable conservative extension of PA and NBG is a finitely-axiomatizable conservative extension of ZFC, where $T_0$ is a conservative extension of $T_1$ iff

- the language of $T_0$ contains the language of $T_1$, and
- the theorems of $T_0$ in the language of $T_1$ are exactly the theorems of $T_1$ (and as a consequence, $T_0$ is consistent iff $T_1$ is).
- The "roughly" above reflects a minor subtlety in the NBG situation, since there are *two* ways of presenting NBG and one of them doesn't strictly fit the situation above. But this is a side issue which I'll ignore for now (if anyone's interested, I can address it).

This turns out to be an instance of a general phenomenon - see the discussion at [this Mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/326470/does-every-first-order-theory-have-a-finitely-axiomatizable-conservative-exten). Roughly speaking, non-finitely-axiomatizable theories "always" have finitely-axiomatizable analogues.

Meanwhile, at least in the case of PA this language expansion is necessary: an alternative proof of Godel's first incompleteness theorem in the specific case of PA, due to Kripke, yields as a corollary (instead of Godel's second incompleteness theorem!) that **no consistent extension of PA in the same language is finitely axiomatizable** (see also the discussion at [this old Mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72062/what-are-some-proofs-of-godels-theorem-which-are-essentially-different-from-t)). The key feature of PA here is a *reflection property*: for each finite subset $S$ of the usual axioms of PA, PA proves the consistency of $S$.

- This narrowly avoids contradiction since "$\forall$" and "$\vdash$" don't commute: just because for each finite $S\subseteq$ PA we have PA $\vdash Con(S)$ doesn't mean we have PA $\vdash \forall S\subseteq_{finite}$ PA$(Con(S))$.)

I believe the same is true of ZF as well, but I don't have a citation to provide immediately (although FWIW I think a Kripke-style argument will still go through there). Certainly it is true that ZF satisfies the same reflection phenomenon as PA (in fact [in a stronger form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle)).